# Why is「から」used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, manga, particle-から

Why is「から」used in the following sentence?

> さてと...われわれも気をうしなうとするか　寝不足すると　農場作業がつらい**から**な。

For my understanding, 「農場作業がつらい」is the result clause while normally 「から」 would follow reason clause.

Answer (score 1):

This から is acting on the clause 寝不足すると農場作業がつらい, which is the reason clause for われわれもきをうしなうとするか. This becomes apparent if you rewrite the sentence to

> 寝不足すると農場作業がつらいからわれわれもきをうしなうとするか。
>
> Farm work is tough if you don't get enough sleep, so let's sleep.

The から is the "so" in this sentence.

Comment: To make sure, 気を失う is "to faint" and it never means "to (voluntarily) sleep / to go to bed". Maybe it's a strange joke.

Comment: Right, it's like saying "let's pass out". Not a common usage, but more of an attempt at humour.